# How do I change the background image on the "Try Ubuntu" screen?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, desktop-background, custom-distributions

When [customizing a live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), how do I change the background image that's displayed behind the "Install" window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling the aforesaid application with appropriate image is one option I think of.

This is your target application:

[Ubiquity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_%28software%29)!

Comment: What part should of the source code should I change?